# How to set a d3Plus Timeline with only Certain years?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

Currently I am trying to draw a HeatMap with a timeline for only 4 Years. My data contains values for the years 1996,2006,2015,2016.However it doesn't have any values for the years in between.

I am wondering if there is any value to display just the years that are set in the data.

My Graph currently looks like this: 
[HeatMap Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toeSa.png.).
However I would like it to display only the years in the data set instead of all the years between 2016-1996. Is there a built in feature for this I am missing?

Here is an example of my code

```
var tree = d3plus.viz()
        .container("#myDiv")
        .data(reformatted)
        .title({
            "value": title
        })
        .font({
            "family": "Open Sans",
            "size":16,
            "color":  "#2D7CBE",
        })

        .type("tree_map")
        .id(categoryDropdown)
        .size(xAxisDropdown)
        .labels({"align": "center", "valign": "top"})
        .time({"value":timeDropdown, "solo": yearsArr[0] })
        .resize(true)
        .color({
            scale:colorpicker
        })
        .draw();
```

In this case solo is set to start the graph at the first year in the yearsArr. The yearsArr is [1996,2006,2015,2016]. Where as timeDropdown is fetching the time values from the data object.

Here is a link to an example of my current code https://codepen.io/Wils0751/pen/ZoYwEb

Any insight to my problem would be of great help Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to display only the years in the data set instead of all the years between 2016-1996

Using Different Scale:

**scaleTime() or scaleLinear()**
it get the domain value of min and max of your data, and get range of your width, so it will display right that

**scaleBand()**
it only count the scale by the array you enter to it

> using `scaleBand()` will help you, read d3 documentation api for more info

or you can filtered function when you draw it, like

```
function(d,i){
  if(d ==  1996){
  return d
 }
}
```

you dont post your working simple code,i didnt know your code, maybe this will help

when i search for your problem, i find this

```
.ui([
  {
    "method" : "size",
    "value"  : [ '1996', '2015' , '2016' ]
  }]
   )
```

change

```
.time({"value":timeDropdown, "solo": yearsArr[0] })
```

to that, but the click function not working anymore

Comment: Thank you @KEKUATAN however, I think the answer you gave me is for the d3 library, where as I am looking for the answer using d3plus? Do you know how to implement d3 functions into d3plus?

Comment: Here is a link to the current working code https://codepen.io/Wils0751/pen/ZoYwEb. I have attempted to add these properties to the D3plus code but it does not seem to work, any insight would be helpful @KEKUATAN